# Opening PDFs in WebView2 based on selection in CheckBoxColumn

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, loops, foreach

So,

In my WPF application, I want my users to be able to open *previews* of invoices, so that they may either verify or discard them. I am letting them check rows (each row representing a invoice) in a `DataGridCheckBoxColumn` in my `DataGrid`, then clicking a button (which runs my `CreateInvoicePreview()` method, see bottom of post), having all of the invoice previews be opened in new windows (one window for each invoice).

Well.. What happens now, is: User checks InvoiceA and InvoiceB. Two invoices are opened, but they are the same: InvoiceC. The correct amount of invoices are always opened, but not the correct instance. If I open the temp folder specified in my file path, I see that all invoices in the datagrid has been saved: InvoiceA through InvoiceJ.

Let me take you through the code.

This is the method that creates that builds and saves the actual PDF's, which the `WebView2` control uses as source, so that it can display them in-app. It is heavily abbreviated.
I have kept the structure with the nested `foreach loops` in case that is relevant.

```
public void CreatePreviewInvoice() {

    /* SQL SERVER CODE
     * SQL SERVER CODE
     * SQL SERVER CODE */

    List<PaidTrip> paidTrips = PaidTrips.ToList();

    tripsGroupedByCompany = paidTrips.GroupBy(pt => pt.LicenseHolderID);

    foreach (IGrouping<string, PaidTrip> companyGroup in tripsGroupedByCompany) {

        /* SQL SERVER CODE
         * SQL SERVER CODE
         * SQL SERVER CODE */

        List<LicenseHolder> licenseHolders = LicenseHolders.ToList();

        IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, PaidTrip>> groupedByVehicle = companyGroup.GroupBy(n => n.VehicleID);

        foreach (IGrouping<string, PaidTrip> vehicleGroup in groupedByVehicle) {

            // Iterating over all data pertaining to each vehicle
            foreach (PaidTrip trip in vehicleGroup) {

            }

        try {

            string userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.Split('\\')[1];
            string fileName = $"FORHÅNDSVISNING - MÅ IKKE SENDES! {LicenseHolderID + "_" + "Faktura_" + InvoiceID}.pdf";
            string filePath = $@"C:\Users\{userName}\AppData\Local\Temp\";

            PdfFilePath = $"{filePath}{fileName}";

            //if (LicenseHolderID == PreviewInvoiceViewModel.SelectedRow.LicenseHolderID) {

            document.Save($"{PdfFilePath}");

            //} else {

            //    return;
            //}                  

        } catch (Exception ex) {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

As you see, towards the end of the method I have commented out a bit of code, which was me trying to implement a way to filter based on the checked rows only. It did not work.

This is the XAML for the `WebView2`:

```
<Wpf:WebView2 
    x:Name="wv_preview_invoice" Loaded="{s:Action CreatePreviewInvoice}" 
    Height="997" Width="702" Canvas.Left="20" Canvas.Top="71" 
    Source="{Binding PdfFilePath}"></Wpf:WebView2>
```

`PdfFilePath` is a property, which is referenced within the method above.
It's given a value within the method, and when `Source` (for the `WebView2`) is called, it is able to get the value from `PdfFilePath`, and thus display the PDF.

But as I said initially, it just creates X amount of instances/windows of the same invoice. Always the same one, because of in what order they are queried from the database.

And finally, here is the method that run when they click whichever invoices they want to preview, it's to open the new window with the `WebView2` control:

```
public void PreviewInvoices() {

    bool success = false;

    foreach (PaidTrip item in PaidTrips) {

        if (item.IsChecked == true) {

            ShowPreviewInvoiceDetailed(item);
            success = true;
        }
    }

    if (!success) {

        MessageBox.Show("You must chose an invoice to preview first.");
    }
}
```

The method that opens the next window where the `WebView2` is, looks like this:

```
 public void ShowPreviewInvoiceDetailed() {

    PreviewInvoiceDetailedViewModel viewModel = new(windowManager);
    windowManager.ShowWindow(viewModel);
}
```

What part (or several parts) of the picture am I missing?

Comment: It seems to me that something is missing on your `CreateInvoicePreview` : `ShowPreviewInvoiceDetailed()` is called for each item checked but no parameter is given to `ShowPreviewInvoiceDetailed` to indicate which `PaidTrip` should be shown.
So maybe change `ShowPreviewInvoiceDetailed` to `ShowPreviewInvoiceDetailed(item)` ?
Side note : [Path.GetTempPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.io.path.gettemppath?view=net-6.0&tabs=windows) will return the path of the current user's temporary folder (instead of what you are doing in `CreatePreviewInvoice`)

Comment: Hello @Ostas, and thank you for commenting! Interesting! I want to pursue that thought, but simlpy adding `(PaidTrip item)` to the name of the method, and then calling `ShowPreviewInvoiceDetailed(item)` as you suggest, did not change anything for me. Am I missing part of it? As for your latter point, thanks!  I love optimalization! :-)

Comment: The implementation of the `ShowPreviewInvoiceDetailed` is not shown so I can't tell you what you need to change but it will need some way to know which InvoicePreview it should show. Otherwise you call it several times but it will always show the same preview which seems like the problem you are having.

Comment: I see, hmm.. `ShowPreviewInvoiceDetailed` is just a navigation method, it just opens the next window where the `WebView2` is.. I added it to me question, would be great if you took a look. Meanwhile I will ponder what you have told me :-)

Comment: Have you gone to the temp folder and opened each of the PDF files to ensure that they're different?

Comment: @user9938 I should've specified that, I'll update my question a bit. The PDF's are saved correctly. This is what happens: InvoiceA is always displayed by the WebView. The first item through my loops. So if I check three invoices in the datagrid (InvoiceB, C and D), it'll give me three clones of InvoiceA, but it'll save all the invoices correctly on file (A through J)..

Comment: @Ole M : I think you confused `ShowPreviewInvoiceDetailed` and `ShowPreviewInvoiceDialog`. What does `ShowPreviewInvoiceDetailed` do ? It has to have some mechanism to know which Invoice has to be shown.

Comment: @Ostas Sorry, I made a mistake. I added the correct method: `ShowPreviewInvoiceDetailed(PaidTrip item)`, and when I call the method inside of `VerifyInvoices`, I do `ShowPreviewInvoiceDetailed(item);` - but it does not make a difference. Appreciate your continued assistance!

Comment: @Ole M : I tried to make a project from the code you provided : it is impossible. Try to make a [minimal reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
For example : you mention `VerifyInvoices` in your answer but it never appears in the code provided. In the code provided `PdfFilePath` is the bound property for the webview but it is only set in `CreatePreviewInvoice` ? 
Please explain the structure of the different viewModels and views.

Comment: You're right. I've been all over the place when it comes to this post. Stressful times!
Sooner rather than later I will refurnish my original question, and my answer.
And if you (or other) can provide me with a better answer, I'll make sure to accept that in stead.

Comment: An image of the files/folders in Solution Explorer may be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to solve this by doing the following:

I made a property; `public static string PreviewedInvoice { get; set; }` in the `ViewModel` of the parent window. In my method that opens the child window (where the preview invoices are to be displayed) I bind it to `LicenseHolderID` of the rows that have a checked `CheckBox`, via `foreach loop`, like such:

```
public void PreviewInvoices() {

    bool success = false;

    foreach (PaidTrip item in PaidTrips) {

        if (item.IsChecked == true) {

            PreviewedInvoice = item.LicenseHolderID;
            ShowPreviewInvoiceDetailed();
            success = true;
        }
    }

    if (!success) {

        MessageBox.Show("You must chose an invoice to preview first.");
    }
}
```

So now I have a way to filter only the checked rows, and make sure only the `LicenseHolderID` which match those in the row with a checked `CheckBox`, are actually saved. I updated my main method:

```
if (LicenseHolderID == PreviewInvoiceViewModel.PreviewedInvoice) {
    document.Save($"{fullPath}");
    SourcePath = fullPath;
}
```

And I bound `SourcePath` to the the source of the `WebView2` in the XAML.

I feel like this is a clunky way of doing it, and I am going back and forth between layers, as a comment (since removed) mentioned.

If anyone can show me a better way, I'm all ears..